# How to get date folder from a subfolders present under nested parent folder using azure data factory

Tags: azure

My source is master/item/itemsold/data/V1/20211201/.csv
( 20211130)
I need to copy latest modified (20211201) folder to sink

Comment: what is the `20211130` reference in your example?

Comment: looks like you are using `Azure Data Factory`, if so, add that tag to get better suggestions or help.

Comment: Master is a parent folder
In dat item/itemsold/data/V1 is subfolders , in V1 folder 20211130, 20211201 this are the sub date folders

Comment: Copy data activity provides `wildcard path` where you can give base path and *.csv , you can also add Filter activity to check if it maps to current date.